# RDMA cluster benchmarking

Tags: rdma

**Requirement :**
I have a cluster of 4 machines and I want to get the collective latency and bandwidth for RDMA Write & RDMA Read operation in full mesh.

I used ib_write_lat/ib_read_lat for latency and ib_write_bw/ib_read_bw for bandwidth. But those are p2p and do not work on clusters.

I want to use a tool that is already available rather as with home grown tools publishing results will be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

You can use MPI to run cluster-wide RDMA-enabled point-to-point or collective benchmarks

Checkout: http://mvapich.cse.ohio-state.edu/benchmarks/

Comment: I see that for collective benchmarks there are lot of tests. How do we know how and what latency is the test is measuring?